# My nav bar isn't according appropriately to my div.container?

Tags: html, css

```css
header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}

nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:gainsboro;
    height:548px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:px;
}

body {
 background-color:Lavender;
}

article {
 float:right;
 height:1250px;
 width:580px;
 text-align:center;
 padding:1em;
 background-color:#5DADE2;
}

section {
    float:left;
 height:1320px;
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
    padding:0em;  
 background-color:#ECF0F1
}

footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;    
}

div.container {
 width:100%;
 border:2px solid purple;
}

.clearfix {
 overflow: auto;
}

.clear {
    clear:right;
    line-height:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

<title>Links - Bannerlord Assignment</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" a href="BannerlordTheme2.css">

</head>

<div class="container">

<body>

<header>

<h1>Further Information</h1>

</header>

<nav>
<a href="Home.html">Home</a><br>
<a href="About.html">About</a><br>
<a href="Media.html">Media</a><br>


</nav>

</body>

</div>

<br class="clear" />

</html>
```

Please do bear with me I am aware this is mind-numbingly basic but I need to start somewhere and I both can't find an answer and can't find a reason why.

My nav bar does not correspond to my div's border and this is less of  a problem but how do I get it so that the nav bar and the header don't overlap when I use the border because as of now the div border is only working on the header.

Comment: add `border` into header instead of `.container`  and move body tag outside of `.container`...

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about adding a 5px top margin to your nav bar, this will account for the 5px border... I think. I'm also still learning. Best of luck, I'll be watching.

Also you always want body to be the outer most thing of what is rendered on the page. So any containers need to be inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

you need overflow hidden to container.

```css
header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}

nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:gainsboro;
    height:548px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:px;
}

body {
 background-color:Lavender;
}

article {
 float:right;
 height:1250px;
 width:580px;
 text-align:center;
 padding:1em;
 background-color:#5DADE2;
}

section {
    float:left;
 height:1320px;
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
    padding:0em;  
 background-color:#ECF0F1
}

footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;    
}

div.container {
 width:100%;
 border:2px solid purple;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.clearfix {
 overflow: auto;
}

.clear {
    clear:right;
    line-height:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

<title>Links - Bannerlord Assignment</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" a href="BannerlordTheme2.css">

</head>

<div class="container">

<body>

<header>

<h1>Further Information</h1>

</header>

<nav>
<a href="Home.html">Home</a><br>
<a href="About.html">About</a><br>
<a href="Media.html">Media</a><br>


</nav>

</body>

</div>

<br class="clear" />

</html>
```

Comment: Do you know why my section, nav and article have to be different heights?

Comment: this kind of issues come due to floating .. you can fix it the by giving clear property to containers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is a) your body tag is in the wrong place (should start just before head, and end just before html tag and b) there is no height declaration on the container.

Adding this code to the CSS:

```
html,body {
    background-color:Lavender;
  height:100%;
}

div.container {
    width:100%;
  height:100%;
    border:2px solid purple;
}
```

and having this to html should work.

```
<body>

<div class="container" style = "border: solid yellow;">


<header>

<h1>Further Information</h1>

</header>
<nav>
<a href="Home.html">Home</a><br>
<a href="About.html">About</a><br>
<a href="Media.html">Media</a><br>


</nav>


</div>

<br class="clear" />
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I found the answer on this site but what does the clear do in this circumstance? A general inquiry.

Comment: It's to get rid of floats, i.e.: clear:right, would not allow any floats to appear on the right of whatever element had the clear property.

Comment: Also just as a note. This didn't seem to work. The above solution did. Coincedentally do you know how to remove the margins around my page? I put margin:0px; in my div.container and it hasn't worked.